# Reading gnuplot legend from csv

Tags: gnuplot

I've got a data.csv file which is structured like this:

```
n    John Smith stats     Sam Williams stats
1                23.4                   44.1
2                32.1                   33.5
3                42.0                   42.1
```

Currently I'm plotting with the following command in gnuplot:

```
plot 'data.csv' using 1:2 title 'John' with lines, '' using 1:3 title 'Sam' with lines
```

The question is how to retrieve first names from the first line of .csv rather than entering them manually?

In addition, is it possible to make it adjustable in case I add a column to the table, so it automatically adds another line with the appropriate title?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You say you have a csv file, so I assume your data file looks like this (and is saved in *infile.csv*):

```
n,John Smith stats,Sam Williams stats
1,23.4,44.1
2,32.1,33.5
3,42.0,42.1
```

If your version of Gnuplot is recent enough, you can use `columnhead` as the `title` argument:

```
echo "
  set datafile separator ','
  plot 'infile.csv' using 1:2 with lines title columnhead
" | gnuplot --persist
```

Or use the `key` option:

```
echo "
  set datafile separator ','
  set key autotitle columnhead
  plot 'infile.csv' using 1:2 with lines, '' using 1:3 with lines
" | gnuplot --persist
```

#### Edit - shorten headings

```
echo "
  set datafile separator ','
  set key autotitle columnhead
  plot '< sed -r \"1 s/,([^ ]+)[^,]+/,\1/g\" infile.csv' using 1:2 with lines, '' using 1:3 with lines
" | gnuplot --persist
```

Output:

[image: Plot of column 1:2 and 1:3 of infile.csv]

*Note [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13375264/1331399) to a follow-up question may also be relevant.*

Comment: columnhead would print the title of the whole column. It is too long and obstructs the plot (there are more and longer columns there), I need only first names shown - this is the problem.

Comment: @sashkello: not sure if you can do that with Gnuplot commands, I've added one way you could do it with GNU sed.

Answer (score 1):

You want to extract only a portion of the columnheader for the legend.

**Update:**

This is a task which you can easily do with gnuplot>=5.4.0. Check `help columnheader` and `help word`.

```
plot for [col=2:4] FILE u 1:col w l title word(columnheader(col),1)
```

However, the above command will not work with gnuplot versions 4.6.0 to 5.2.8. Whereas `title columnheader(col)` will work, but `title word(columnheader(col),1)` will not.

**Workaround:** (for gnuplot versions 4.6.0 to 5.2.8)

Again a strange *gnuplot-only* workaround.
In short: In a `plot for` loop which starts at 1 you assign the header of  column 2 to the variable `myHeader`, however, you are plotting nothing (`NaN`) with title `myHeader=''` (empty string will not generate a keyentry). In the next iteration you plot column 2, with the previously extracted header. This will continue until the last column (here: `N=4`).

**Data:** `SO13371449.csv` (some more example data added)

```
n,    John Smith stats,     Sam Williams stats,    Tom Muller stats
1,                23.4,                   44.1,                22.1
2,                32.1,                   33.5,                25.7
3,                42.0,                   42.1,                40.0
```

**Script:** (works for gnuplot>=4.6.0)

```
### get only a portion of columnheader for the title (gnuplot>=4.6.0)
reset

FILE = "SO13371449.csv"

set datafile separator ","
myHeader = ''
N=4
plot for [col=1:N] FILE u ($0==0 && col<N ? myHeader=word(strcol(col+1),1) : 0, \
     col==1 ? NaN : $1):col w lp pt 7 title myHeader
### end of script
```

**Result:** (created with gnuplot 4.6.0)

[image]